# PHP and MySQL optional WHERE <column> LIKE conditions

Tags: mysql, where-clause, option-type, sql-like

I am trying to write a SQL query for search on multiple optional fields. First I made it with *column_name = user entered value*, that works fine;

But when I changed it to *column_name LIKE %user entered value%* it comes as **%'value'%** and the single quotes (') is creating trouble. Please advice me how to overcome this.

```
mysql_select_db($database_BMProperty, $BMProperty);

if(isset($_POST['City']))       {$A=sprintf(GetSQLValueString($_POST['City'], "text"));}    else {$A="any";}

if(isset($_POST['Locality']))   {$B=**"%".sprintf(GetSQLValueString($_POST['Locality'], "text"))."%"**;}else {$B="any";}

if(isset($_POST['PIN']))        {$C=sprintf(GetSQLValueString($_POST['PIN'], "text"));}     else {$C="any";}

if(isset($_POST['BedRooms']))   {$D=sprintf(GetSQLValueString($_POST['BedRooms'], "int"));} else {$D="any";}

if(isset($_POST['Area']))       {$E=sprintf(GetSQLValueString($_POST['Area'], "int"));}     else {$E="any";}

if(isset($_POST['BuyRent']))    {$F=sprintf(GetSQLValueString($_POST['BuyRent'], "int"));}  else {$F="any";}

$string = "";

if(isset($_POST['City'])&& $_POST['City'] !='')     {$string= "CITY = $A";
}

if(isset($_POST['Locality']) && $_POST['Locality'] !='' )   {if($string != "") {$string .= " **AND LOCALITY LIKE $B**";} else {$string .= "LOCALITY = $B";}
}

if(isset($_POST['PIN']) && $_POST['PIN'] != '')     {   if($string != "") {$string .= " AND PIN = $C";} else {$string .= "PIN = $C";}
}

if(isset($_POST['BedRooms']) && $_POST['BedRooms'] != '' )  {   if($string != "") {$string .= " AND BEDROOMS = $D";} else {$string .= "BEDROOMS = $D";}
}

if(isset($_POST['Area']) && $_POST['Area'] !='')        {   if($string != "") {$string .= " AND AREA = $E";} else {$string .= "AREA = $E";} 
}

if($F != 'any'){ // or whatever you need
    $where[] = "BUYRENT = $F";
    if($string != "") {$string .= " AND BUYRENT = $F";} else {$string .= "BUYRENT = $F";}   
}


$query = "SELECT * FROM ads";

if($string){
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . $string;
}
```

The query is coming like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE CITY = 'mumbai' AND LOCALITY LIKE %'thane'% AND BUYRENT = 1
```

City and BuyRent are mandatory fields.

Comment: concatenate `'%'` with `$_POST['Locality']` ie `'%' . $_POST['Locality'] . '%'`. Also consider to sanitize special LIKE symbols `%_`. And finally this http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated